# What is the command line function to reconnect to a running X server?

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, x-server

I was working on some stuff on my desktop running Ubuntu 11.04. I bumped the button sequence, i forget what it even is now, that throws you back to the terminal. So I log in and hear the music I was working on continue to play, that gives me hope that I haven't lost my work. But I can't figure out what to type to reconnect to the X server. `xinit` and `startx` didn't work.

so what do I need to type to reconnect to that running X server?

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, you can switch between virtual terminals by using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F*x*</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F*x*</kbd> if inside an X11 session).

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> should work for you. (X11 starts on the first available tty, which is often tty7, as ttys 1-6 are set up by console logins in most Linux distributions.)

If it is not tty7 for some reason, run `who` or `w` and look for "`Xorg`" or "`gdm`" in the output.